# Woocommerce creating order programmatically not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create woocommerce order programmatically.
It works fine for logged in users but when I try to create it using a guest account then it does not work.
Here is my code

```
$cart = WC()->cart;
$order_data = array(
              'status' => apply_filters('woocommerce_default_order_status', 'pending'),
              'customer_id' => get_current_user_id()
            );
            $checkout = WC()->checkout();
            $order_id = $checkout->create_order($order_data);
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id());
            $order->calculate_totals();
```

Please help with this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that get_current_user_id() returns 0 if it cannot find a user. When you pass in 0 as a customer_id its breaking the create order.

Try:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if($user_id != 0){
    $order_data = array(
        'status' => apply_filters('woocommerce_default_order_status', 'pending'),
        'customer_id' => get_current_user_id()
     );
} else {
    $order_data = array(
        'status' => apply_filters('woocommerce_default_order_status', 'pending')
    );
}
```

Then create your order.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But it not works.
Actually, for testing purpose I have tried $order = wc_create_order(); also and it works for logged in user but not for guest user. Not sure why.
FYI it is Woocommerce 3.7.0